# gcc5.2 abi change -> compatibility guaranteed?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, boost, abi

I have the following situation (Ubuntu 15.10 and Debian Testing)

I have Lib A which is compiled without cxx11 and a lib B that uses -std=c++11. B includes and links against A, A uses boost.

If i link B to A, the application a A created crashes during dynload.
If i compile A without cxx11 or B with cxx11 everything works fine.

My question: as far i understood the ABI namespace add on should guarantee shuch kind of problem. Am i wrong here?

I created a example project to clarify the problem:
https://github.com/goldhoorn/sandbox/tree/gcc5.2-issue
test1 failed, the other tests passing.

GDB tells me:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7bceb2e in _GLOBAL__sub_I_Lib.cpp () from ./libmyLib.so
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7bceb2e in _GLOBAL__sub_I_Lib.cpp () from ./libmyLib.so
#1  0x00007ffff7deaa0a in call_init (l=<optimized out>, argc=argc@entry=1, 
argv=argv@entry=0x7fffffffe688, env=env@entry=0x7fffffffe698)
at dl-init.c:78
#2  0x00007ffff7deaaf3 in call_init (env=0x7fffffffe698, argv=0x7fffffffe688, 
argc=1, l=<optimized out>) at dl-init.c:36
#3  _dl_init (main_map=0x7ffff7ffe1a8, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe688, 
env=0x7fffffffe698) at dl-init.c:126
#4  0x00007ffff7ddd1ca in _dl_start_user () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#5  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007fffffffe89f in ?? ()
#7  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Result from Valgrind:

```
goldhoorn@debian:/tmp/example$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. valgrind --show-below-main=yes ./main 
==17140== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==17140== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==17140== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==17140== Command: ./main
==17140== 
==17140== 
==17140== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==17140==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x401FE8
==17140==    at 0x4E3EB2E: _GLOBAL__sub_I_Lib.cpp (in /tmp/example/libmyLib.so)
==17140==    by 0x400EA09: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:78)
==17140==    by 0x400EAF2: call_init (dl-init.c:36)
==17140==    by 0x400EAF2: _dl_init (dl-init.c:126)
==17140==    by 0x40011C9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so)
==17140== 
==17140== HEAP SUMMARY:
==17140==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==17140==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 72,704 bytes allocated
==17140== 
==17140== LEAK SUMMARY:
==17140==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17140==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17140==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17140==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==17140==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17140== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==17140== 
==17140== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==17140== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Did you compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`? Did you use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), `gdb`, and [address sanitizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) to understand your bug?  plase show some example code ([MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)...) in your question... so please **edit your question** to improve it

Comment: Actually at least `std::string` on ABI level different between `-std=c++11` and `-std=c=+03`, so mix of different standards make create random crashes. Plus c++11 not implemented instantly, so with some old gcc `std::string`  not mach `c++11` requirements, so you can not see any crashes.

Comment: @user1034749 As far i understood should the new ABI result in unlinkebale code. Thats my qeustion why this does not happen here: http://developerblog.redhat.com/2015/02/05/gcc5-and-the-c11-abi/

Comment: link error produced if `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` used, I don't see in your make file such define

Comment: @user1034749: The -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0  disables only the newly introduced ABI standart afaik. Therefore it does not change the behaviour (however it would only make it worse if set)

Comment: For all readers i assume this is a gcc bug, i created a gcc-bug report: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68195

Comment: @user1034749 (and whoever upvoted the comment): that's not true, the `std::string` ABI is independent of the `-std` flag used. Mixing different standard dialects produces ABI compatible code.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Yeah, I see, but gcc 4.7 sizeof(std::string) == 8, while gcc 5.2 sizeof(std::string) == 32, but sizeof(std::string) not change by `-std` flag in both gcc versions

Comment: @user1034749, which is irrelevant here because everything is compiled with the same version. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/libstdc++/manual/manual/using_dual_abi.html for more information on the change.

Comment: @JonathanWakely may be TS compile code of library with `-std=c++03` while main program with `-std=c++11` because of he thinks that library will be compatible with some binaries compiled with old version of `gcc`, then my comment relevant, and the whole idea of question is wrong as you point out that `-std` not change  ABI.

Comment: @JonathanWakely by the way can you reproduce problem in [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68195)? Jan Hubicka point out that he can not reproduce problem and disappeared, even if bisect show his commit :(

Comment: Afaik the dual abi (introduced by gcc 5.2) shout generate different symbols. So even the code might be incompatible i should get a linker failure?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your library A against the list of Cxx11 ABI backward incompatibilities: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Cxx11AbiCompatibility

> The C++98 language is ABI-compatible with the C++11 language, but several places in the library break compatibility. This makes it dangerous to link C++98 objects with C++11 objects.